# CSSTransition does not work. V2 react-transition-group

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

So, I have a tiny part of code where I'm trying to add an animation as wrapper for `Tooltip Nodes`. But perhaps I do something wrong, because I do not see on the screen any `animation` appearing during `mount`.

Moreover, it even does not fire `console.log` on `onEnter` event. Why?

Thanks.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

import styles from './index.scss'
import './anim.scss'

class ToolTip extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
        <CSSTransition
          in={true}
          classNames={'tooltip'}
          timeout={3000}
          onEnter={() => { console.log('FIRED!') }}
        >
          <div className={`${styles.tooltipContainer}`}>
            <span className={styles.title}>{'title'}</span>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
    )
  }
}

export default ToolTip
```

Edit:

my `anim.scss` file:

```
.tooltip-enter {
  opacity: 0;

  &.tooltip-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tooltip-exit {
  opacity: 1;

  &.tooltip-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is hiding under the composition of css-transition-group usage. As mentioned by @Dhaval you need a some action to trigger the css transition. So, as I see, you trying to make something without `Hello` state manipulation.

Probably, you trying to use this Component wrapped in animation inside some other Component. If yes, we need to set CSS Transition Group animation wrapper inside this "other" Component and by him wrap our `Hello` Component.

See below:

```
// ..some Wrapper Component where we need to use our Hello Component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Hello from '../someWhere'
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import './anim.scss'

class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isAnimation: false,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <CSSTransition
                    in={this.state.isAnimation}
                    classNames={'tooltip'}
                    timeout={300}
                    onEnter={() => {
                        console.log('FIRED!');
                    }}
                >
                    <Hello />
                </CSSTransition>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default SomeComponent;
```

and

```
// ..our updated Hello Component

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'

import styles from './index.scss'

class Hello extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className={`${styles.tooltipContainer}`}>
          <span className={styles.title}>{'title'}</span>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Hello

This is should help you!
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, you are right, I understand this not so far ago too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the demo code mentioned below and in this code when you click on it, it will log the console with fired.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

class Hello extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isAnimation: false,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <CSSTransition
                    in={this.state.isAnimation}
                    classNames={'tooltip'}
                    timeout={300}
                    onEnter={() => {
                        console.log('FIRED!');
                    }}
                >
                    <div className="star">⭐</div>
                </CSSTransition>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({ isAnimation: true });
                    }}
                >
                    Click
                </button>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default Hello;
```

[Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/goyOkHjfB8wxU4hY?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: Hi. This is the demo from Official site. It works, I know, but not for my case.

Comment: @MaxTravis: as per my observation you have to do some action and make in true based on the action in CSSTransition, if you directly give it to in={true} not works, that's my observation